# Launching a GWT module when clicking on an XML

Tags: gwt

Greetings,

I'm looking for a way to launch a GWT module when a user clicks on an XML file and have the module consume the xml data.  Ideally I would like to render the XML in a rich manner and would prefer to use GWT controls instead of having to lay it out by hand via xslt + javascript.

I'm supposing one way would be to point the xml to a well known xslt that creates a simple html page that forces a redirect to the gwt module but how would I transfer the xml data to said module to allow for enhanced formatting?

Another way would be to have the process that produces the xml also include the bootstrap gwt module but it would be creating multiple bootstrap instances over time and pollute the user's directory.

The use case is that a user would run this app on their local machine which outputs an XML file.  If they try and view the xml file in a browser, I'd like to have the GWT module take over and present the data accordingly.  I would rather they not have to go to a page and upload the data manually.

Appreciate any ideas on the matter.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

If it's something that runs on the user's machine, I would recommend to ship an executable, or generate a parallel HTML file to present the data. JavaScript run from file:/// will not be able to acces the filesystem.

Comment: Would it not be possible to have the xslt generate a redirect to the server posting the xml data?  A server side process could capture this xml and wrap it with the gwt bootstrap (making the xml available as a var on the page).  The issue seems to be that the xml would make multiple trips across the network which could hurt performance given the size (once to post to server and once to return to client formatted).

Comment: If you have control over the XSLT process, I suppose you could generate a host page with the xml data available as a variable (in JSON format for example) to GWT, as you say. The only bad thing is that the data would be duplicated, once in the original XML file, and again in the GWT host page file.